# How to force type `X` columns to wrap their contents when using `\multicolumn` command?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I got a table that has multicolumns within type `X` columns. In 'The LaTeX Companion', it is explicitly stated that "Any `\multicolumn` entries that cross any X column should not be used." Violation of the rule gives anomalies like this

[image]

What if I still want to get the benefit of type `X` columns (automatically match column width or even make the width of one column given in terms of the other column width), but I want to use `\multicolumn`? Is there a way to get both?

The output I want is something like

[image]

But, of course, without the lines that extend beyond table width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathastext}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htb]

    % Table options

    % Caption
    \caption{Comparison of Time Consumed to Estimate One $\mathnormalbold{Z}_{bus}$ Element}
    \label{table:time_cons_comp}

    % Center the table
    \centering


    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{C |C |C |C}

        \toprule

        \multirow{3}{=}{\centering System Size} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Time Needed With Our Approach (Extended Brown's Method)}
        \\
        \Xcline{2-4}{0.1mm}

        & min & mean & max
        \\
        \Xhline{0.1mm}

        200-bus & $6\times10^{-6}$ & $7.7\times10^{-6}$ & $9\times10^{-6}$
        \\
        \Xhline{0.1mm}

        2383-bus & $6\times10^{-6}$ & $9.1\times10^{-6}$ & $13\times10^{-6}$
        \\
        \Xhline{0.1mm}

        3120-bus & $8\times10^{-6}$ & $9.7\times10^{-6}$ & $11\times10^{-6}$
        \\
        \hline
        \hline

        \multirow{3}{=}{\centering System Size} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Time Needed With Conventional Brown's Method}
        \\

        \Xcline{2-4}{0.1mm}

        & min & mean & max
        \\
        \Xhline{0.1mm}

        200-bus & $0.089$ & $0.092$ & $0.1000$
        \\
        \Xhline{0.1mm}

        2383-bus & $163.8$ & $166.2$ & $172.5$
        \\
        \Xhline{0.1mm}

        3120-bus & $387.2$ & $398.8$ & $415.6$
        \\


        \bottomrule

    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in your definition of new column you should remove all empty spaces
- text in multicolum`cell` is wider than width of the spanned cells
- command `\mathnormalbold` is unknown (at least to me)

with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%\usepackage{booktabs}    % not used in this table
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X }

\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \caption{Comparison of Time Consumed to Estimate One $\mathbf{Z}_{bus}$ Element}
    \label{table:time_cons_comp}
   \centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{C *{3}{|>{$}C<{$} } }
    \Xhline{0.3mm}
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering System Size}
    & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
                Time Needed With Our Approach \newline
                (Extended Brown's Method)}                          \\
 \Xcline{2-4}{0.1mm}
         & min & mean & max                                         \\
    \Xhline{0.1mm}
200-bus  & 6\times10^{-6}   & 7.7\times10^{-6}  &  9\times10^{-6}   \\
    \Xhline{0.1mm}
2383-bus & 6\times10^{-6}   & 9.1\times10^{-6}  & 13\times10^{-6}   \\
    \Xhline{0.1mm}
3120-bus & 8\times10^{-6}   & 9.7\times10^{-6}  & 11\times10^{-6}   \\
        \hline
        \hline
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering System Size}
    & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
                Time Needed With\newline
                Conventional Brown's Method}                        \\
    \Xcline{2-4}{0.1mm}
         & min & mean & max                                         \\
    \Xhline{0.1mm}
200-bus  & 0.089    & 0.092     & 0.100                             \\
    \Xhline{0.1mm}
2383-bus & 163.8    & 166.2     & 172.5                             \\
    \Xhline{0.1mm}
3120-bus & 387.2    & 398.8     & 415.6                             \\

    \Xhline{0.3mm}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

you will obtain the following result:

[image]

**edit:**
i consider [David Carlisle's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) comment regarding width of the `multicolumn` cells. also considering [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician) for removing all not necessary horisontal and vertical lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%\usepackage{booktabs} not used
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\Centering}X }

\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \caption{Comparison of Time Consumed to Estimate One $\mathbf{Z}_{bus}$ Element}
    \label{table:time_cons_comp}
   \centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{C *{3}{>{$}C<{$} }}
    \Xhline{0.3mm}
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering System Size}
    & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
                Time Needed With Our Approach \newline
                (Extended Brown's Method)}                          \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & min & mean & max                                              \\
    \hline
200-bus  & 6\times10^{-6}   & 7.7\times10^{-6}  &  9\times10^{-6}   \\
2383-bus & 6\times10^{-6}   & 9.1\times10^{-6}  & 13\times10^{-6}   \\
3120-bus & 8\times10^{-6}   & 9.7\times10^{-6}  & 11\times10^{-6}   \\
        \hline
        \hline
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering System Size}
    & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
                Time Needed With\newline 
                Conventional Brown's Method}                        \\
    \cline{2-4} & min & mean & max                                              \\
    \Xhline{0.1mm}
200-bus  & 0.089    & 0.092     & 0.100                             \\
2383-bus & 163.8    & 166.2     & 172.5                             \\
3120-bus & 387.2    & 398.8     & 415.6                             \\
   \Xhline{0.3mm}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, although it still has vertical rules ;)

Comment: @TeXnician, i don't know, why i not remove them, usually i do so :-)

Comment: actually it should probably be `\hsize\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax`  (`tabularx` really ought to make this easier)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, `+2arrayrulewidth` :-) . since `3\hsize` gives enough width for text in two lines, i left this out for make code slightly shorter. now i correct this.

Comment: @Zarko I was assuming you'd remove the rules:-) although it's not obvious the shorter parbox will be flush left so the spanning head is not centred correctly without the width adjustment.

Comment: Did the contents of the second 3-column header cell get clobbered?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution. The width of the three-column header cell is calculated as `3\hsize+ 4\tabcolsep`, where `\hsize` is the usable width of each of the three data columns. (The value of `\hsize` is calculated automatically by `tabularx`.) Choosing `3\hsize+4\tabcolsep` takes into account that the combination of the three data columns is wider than the simple sum of the three individual columns: There are also two instances of intercolumn whitespace, each in the amount of `2\tabcolsep`, to take into account.

The code shown below also loads the `siunitx` package and employs that package's `\num` macro, to streamline the entry of numbers in scientific format. Separately, I suggest omitting all vertical lines: they just aren't needed. Indeed, one could argue that the omission of the vertical lines *improves* the overall readability of the table considerably.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% (I've simplified the preamble to the minimum that's required.)
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx} % new -- for "\num" macro
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]

    \caption{Comparison of Times Consumed to Estimate One $Z_{\mathrm{bus}}$ Element}
    \label{table:time_cons_comp}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{@{}lCCC@{}}
        \toprule
        System Size & 
        \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
        Time Needed with Our Approach (Extended Brown's Method)}\\
        \cmidrule(l){2-4}
        & min & mean & max\\
        \midrule
        200-bus  & \num{6e-6} & \num{7.7e-6} & \num{9e-6}  \\
        2383-bus & \num{6e-6} & \num{9.1e-6} & \num{3e-6}  \\
        3120-bus & \num{8e-6} & \num{9.7e-6} & \num{11e-6} \\
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        System Size & 
        \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
        Time Needed with Conventional~Brown's Method}\\
        \cmidrule(l){2-4}
        & min & mean & max\\
        \midrule
        200-bus  & $0.089$ & $0.092$ & $0.100$ \\
        2383-bus & $163.8$ & $166.2$ & $172.5$ \\
        3120-bus & $387.2$ & $398.8$ & $415.6$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```