# How to properly center (or justify) the contents of `\multicolumn` when it crosses type `X` columns?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

In a previous question ([How to force type `X` columns to wrap their contents when using `\multicolumn` command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452194/how-to-force-type-x-columns-to-wrap-their-contents-when-using-multicolumn-c)), I asked for a code that allows me to use `\multicolumn` command that crosses type `X` columns. Zarko provided me with a code that solves the my issue

`multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
                Time Needed With Our Approach \newline
                (Extended Brown's Method)}`

Inspired by his answer, I wrote a custom command as follows

`\newcommand{\multcolhsize}[1]{\dimexpr #1\hsize + #1\tabcolsep + \tabcolsep \relax}`

Which allows for the concise application of the original code provided by Zarko

`\multicolumn{n}{>{\hsize=\multcolhsize{n}\}X}{<text>}`

However, right now, when using the code, it does not seem that the text is not properly justified when using `\justifying\arraybackslash` in the preamble of type `X` columns. Similarly, it does not seem to go exactly to the center when using `\centering\arraybackslash`

[image]

[image]

Clearly, the custom command might be improved further to guarantee that it goes exactly to the center or justifies properly for the specified columns.

```
\documentclass{book}

    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

        \geometry{twoside=true, showframe=false}

        % Horizontal
        \geometry{inner=10mm, outer=10mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=5mm, marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=15mm}

        % Vertical
        \geometry{top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includehead=true, includefoot=true, headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}

    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
        \def \tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
        \newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash\Centering}X}

        \newcommand{\multcolhsize}[1]{\dimexpr #1\hsize + #1\tabcolsep + \tabcolsep \relax}

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htp]

    \def \tabularxcolumn#1{p{#1}}

    \caption{Caption}

    \centering

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r p{3cm} *{10}{C}}

        \toprule

        &
        &
        \multicolumn{10}{>{\hsize=\multcolhsize{10}\centering\arraybackslash}X}{Complexity}
        \\
        \cmidrule(l){3-12}

        &
        Description &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 1} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 2} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 3} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 4} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 5} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 6} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 7} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 8} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 9} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 10}
        \\
        \cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-12}

        1. &
        Description A &
        VS &
        S &
        VS &
        S &
        VS &
        S &
        C &
        VC &
        C &
        VC
        \\
        \addlinespace[0.1cm]

        2. &
        Description B &
        S &
        C &
        S &
        C &
        S &
        C &
        S &
        C &
        S &
        C
        \\
        \addlinespace[0.1cm]

        3. &
        Description C &
        N &
        N &
        N &
        N &
        N &
        N &
        Y &
        VC &
        Y &
        VC
        \\
        \addlinespace[0.1cm]

        \bottomrule

    \end{tabularx}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
\newcommand{\multcolhsize}[1]{\dimexpr #1\hsize + #1\tabcolsep + \tabcolsep \relax}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\multcolhsize}[2]{\dimexpr #1\hsize + #2\tabcolsep \relax}
```

Then, in the

```
\multicolumn{10}{>{\hsize=\multcolhsize{10}\centering\arraybackslash}X}{Complexity}
```

statement, you need to change

```
\hsize=\multcolhsize{10}
```

to

```
\hsize=\multcolhsize{10}{18}
```

However, since the column header -- "Complexity" -- is quite short, you'd be perfectly ok to write

```
\multicolumn{10}{c}{Complexity}
```

"Why the `18` in `\multcolhsize{10}{18}`?", you may ask. LaTeX by default automatically inserts whitespace in the amount of `\tabcolsep` on both sides any tabular-type column. The total amount of whitespace *between* two columns thus amounts `2\tabcolsep`. To calculate the total usable width of the `\multicolumn{10}{...}{...}` column, one has to allow for both 10`\hsize` *and* 2*9=18`\tabcolsep`.

---

*Addendum*: Armed with this information, let's go back to [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452196/5001), in which he wrote

```
\multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{...}
```

Since three columns are being spanned, `3\hsize` must be right. But with three columns, there are two inter-column spaces to consider, each with width `2\tabcolsep`. Hence, the total usable width indeed equals `3\hsize+4\tabcolsep`.

---

Finally, here's the output of the adjusted form of your MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper,twoside=true}
    % Horizontal
    \geometry{inner=10mm, outer=10mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=5mm, 
              marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=15mm}
    % Vertical
    \geometry{top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includehead=true, 
              includefoot=true, headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}

    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash\Centering}X}
    % Another way to define '\multcolhsize', with just 1 argument
    \newcommand{\multcolhsize}[1]{\dimexpr%   
         #1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+#1\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep\relax}

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

    \def\tabularxcolumn#1{p{#1}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \centering

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r p{3cm} *{10}{C}}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{10}{>{\hsize=\multcolhsize{10}\Centering}X}{Complexity}
    \\
    \cmidrule(l){3-12}
    & Description &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 1} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 2} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 3} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 4} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 5} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 6} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 7} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 8} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 9} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 10} \\
    \midrule
    1. & Description A & VS & S & VS & S & VS & S & C & VC & C & VC \\
    \addlinespace
    2. & Description B & S & C & S & C & S & C & S & C & S & C \\
    \addlinespace
    3. & Description C & N & N & N & N & N & N & Y & VC & Y & VC \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer. However, it might be too redundant to try calculating how much `\tabcolsep` to add. Is it possible to get a command with a single argument that automatically calculates the second value?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh - For the case at hand, surely `\multicolumn{10}{c}{Complexity}` must be the easiest way to go. The formula for the total usable width is `n\hsize+2(n-1)\tabcolsep`. I suppose there's nothing to stop you from writing `\newcommand{\multcolhsize}[1]{\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+#1\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep\relax}`, is there?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The new definition works very well. Hopefully, I would like that you mention it explicitly by modifying your original answer. However, the numerical illustration you provided is also great, which helps others understand why I get the anomaly in my original code.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh - I've posted an further addendum, with your MWE adapted so that `\multcolhsize` takes just 1 argument.

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray): multicolumn, `X` column and cell centering work as expected.

Note you need to put trim option `l` of `\cmidrule` command in the square brackets.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,twoside=true}
% Horizontal
\geometry{inner=10mm, outer=10mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=5mm, 
          marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=15mm}
% Vertical
\geometry{top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includehead=true, 
          includefoot=true, headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \caption{Caption}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{r p{3cm} *{10}{X[c]}}
    \toprule
    & & \SetCell[c=10]{c} Complexity & & & & & & & & & 
    \\
    \cmidrule[l]{3-12}
    & Description &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 1} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 2} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 3} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 4} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 5} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 6} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 7} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 8} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 9} &
        \adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 10} \\
    \midrule
    1. & Description A & VS & S & VS & S & VS & S & C & VC & C & VC \\
    \addlinespace
    2. & Description B & S & C & S & C & S & C & S & C & S & C \\
    \addlinespace
    3. & Description C & N & N & N & N & N & N & Y & VC & Y & VC \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why using `tabularx`. This seems more a job for `tabular*`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\geometry{
  twoside=true,
  showframe=false,
  % Horizontal
  inner=10mm,
  outer=10mm,
  includemp=true,
  bindingoffset=5mm,
  marginparsep=3.5mm,
  marginparwidth=15mm,
  % Vertical
  top=20mm,
  vmarginratio=3:5,
  includehead=true,
  includefoot=true,
  headheight=8pt,
  headsep=14pt,
  footskip=5mm,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htp]

\caption{Caption}

\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{r l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{10}{c}}
\toprule
&& \multicolumn{10}{c}{Complexity}
\\
\cmidrule(r){3-12}
&
Description &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 1} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 2} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 3} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 4} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 5} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 6} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 7} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 8} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 9} &
\adjustbox{rotate=90}{Method 10}
\\
\cmidrule(l){2-2} \cmidrule(r){3-12}

1. & Description A & VS & S & VS & S & VS & S & C & VC & C & VC \\
\addlinespace[0.1cm]

2. & Description B & S & C & S & C & S & C & S & C & S & C \\
\addlinespace[0.1cm]

3. & Description C & N & N & N & N & N & N & Y & VC & Y & VC \\
\addlinespace[0.1cm]

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid the rotated headers, though.

```latex
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{r l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{10}{c}}
\toprule
& Description & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Complexity methods} \\
\cmidrule(r){3-12}
&& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\midrule

1. & Description A & VS & S & VS & S & VS & S & C & VC & C & VC \\
\addlinespace[0.1cm]

2. & Description B & S & C & S & C & S & C & S & C & S & C \\
\addlinespace[0.1cm]

3. & Description C & N & N & N & N & N & N & Y & VC & Y & VC \\
\addlinespace[0.1cm]

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
```

[image]

Comment: I usually use `tabularx` because it accepts type `X` columns, which might be systematically determined. For instance, I might need to specify that a column be twice the size of another column, while the entire width must be equal to the text or column width. Meeting such criteria simultaneously is easier with `tabularx`

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh This doesn't seem the case here. You can use a screwdriver for opening a bottle of orange juice, but a bottle opener is better.

Comment: I suppose a purposeful reason for using a `tabularx` environment in the table at hand, which features 10 data columns, is to assure that 10 data columns all have the exact same width. If one looks closely at the screenshots you posted (generated with the help of `tabular*`, one notices that data columns 2, 4, 4, 7 and 9 are ever so slightly narrower than the other five. Not a huge distraction, though, for sure. But if for some reason it's necessary for all 10 data columns to have the exact same width, `tabularx` is the way to go.

Comment: @egreg The original tables I use in the paper are `tabularx` which look more professional when they extend along the entire text width. I just want to verify that any proposed solution works well with I typically use

Comment: @Mico That can be cured in several ways, the last of which to try is `tabularx`.